# prove that $ f\left(\frac{x+y}{x-y}\right)=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{f(x)-f(y)} $ is one-one.

Tags: functions

**Question** -

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that
$$
f\left(\frac{x+y}{x-y}\right)=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{f(x)-f(y)}
$$
for all $x \neq y$ .prove that $f$ is one-one.

by letting $f(m)=f(n)$  i am not able to prove that m=n ...
any help will  be appreciated

thankyou

Comment: For the equation to make sense you have to assume that $f(x) \neq f(y)$ whenver $x \neq y$. This makes $f$ one-to-one.

Comment: If we rewrite the functional equation as "$f(\frac{x+y}{x-y})(f(x)-f(y))=f(x)+f(y)$ whenever $x\ne y$", then the zero-function is also a solution (and not one-one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\ne y$, to avoid a division by $0$ we also require $f(x)\ne f(y)$.

Comment: oh,yes sorry for stupid question...i forgot another condition of a function to be one-one...thanks